# How do people carry camping propane in a car when traveling?

Tags: camping, fuel, propane-tank

I'm very new to camping. In fact..I'm trying to prepare for my first camping. One thing that I can't find answer even after googling and searching this site is..how people travel with camping stove and its fuel.

It looks like storing propane in a car is somewhat dangerous, especially when it is hot outside. I plan to camp in a desert in summer.

Is it safe to travel in a car with camping propane?

What's the safety guideline?

Comment: Typically cars get the hottest when you're not in them, parked in the sun for an afternoon. Even if you leave the windows slightly open. Since parking in the shade is not always an option and the same thing goes for taking you propane with you I'm curious what kind of good tips you'll get. I've personally never had a gas tank explode on me (I suppose it's pretty rare to begin with), but I haven't travelled through a desert with one either.

Comment: @Monster Thank you Monster. I was a little bit worried since all the answers I found over the web suggest not to carry it, but I see a lot of people travel with a propane..